# After rich:extendedDataTable sortby, other actions are not getting executed

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have several tabs and one of the tabs uses `rich:extendedDataTable`. If `sortBy` is clicked in the page where table is used and if I navigate to another page, it looks for the bean of the old page and throws an error saying that `sortyBy` of the column is undefined.

E.g. If I use `sortBy` on userId in tab1 (where the column must have `sortBy="#{data.userId}"`) and then I click on tab2, it looks for the `data.userId` and throws an error. I am using Richfaces version 3.2.2SR1.

Can anyone help me on this?

Here is the complete trace:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /amendapplication/historyDetails.xhtml @33,174 sortBy="#{data.statusChangeTime}": Property 'statusChangeTime' not found on type uk.gov.wales.rpd.domain.applicationmanagement.ApplicationAttributeEntity
    com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:73)
    org.richfaces.model.impl.expressive.ValueBindingExpression.evaluate(ValueBindingExpression.java:59)
    org.richfaces.model.impl.expressive.ObjectWrapperFactory.wrapObject(ObjectWrapperFactory.java:189)
    org.richfaces.model.ModifiableModel$RowKeyWrapperFactory.wrapObject(ModifiableModel.java:57)
    org.richfaces.model.impl.expressive.ObjectWrapperFactory$2.convert(ObjectWrapperFactory.java:177)
    org.richfaces.model.impl.expressive.ObjectWrapperFactory.convertList(ObjectWrapperFactory.java:138)
    org.richfaces.model.impl.expressive.ObjectWrapperFactory.wrapList(ObjectWrapperFactory.java:175)
    org.richfaces.model.ModifiableModel.sort(ModifiableModel.java:235)
    org.richfaces.model.ModifiableModel.modify(ModifiableModel.java:206)
    org.richfaces.component.UIExtendedDataTable.createDataModel(UIExtendedDataTable.java:310)
    org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptor.getExtendedDataModel(UIDataAdaptor.java:621)
    org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptor.setRowKey(UIDataAdaptor.java:339)
    org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptor.iterate(UIDataAdaptor.java:1034)
    org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptor.processDecodes(UIDataAdaptor.java:1158)
    org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptor.processDecodes(UIDataAdaptor.java:1168)
    javax.faces.component.UIForm.processDecodes(UIForm.java:209)
    org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot$1.invokeContextCallback(AjaxViewRoot.java:392)
    org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:238)
    org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processDecodes(AjaxViewRoot.java:409)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:341)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:177)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:267)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:380)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:507)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like as if you've bound multiple different datatables to the same `UIData` property, or that you're reusing the same bean property to supply different datamodels depending on the displayed tab/table.

You can and should not reuse the one and the same bean property for different components and/or different value purposes. Verify if anything is right in your beans.